# Keypress Event for <p:autoComplete>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have the requirement to do a bit customizing with the "keypress" event on basis of the auto-completion component, but it seems to me it is completely registered by Primefaces. So far I have tried the following two ways:

1)

```
    <p:autoComplete id="inputResID" 
                    value="#{searchController.searchQuery}" 
                    completeMethod="#{searchController.completeText}" 
                    size="30" 
                    maxResults="10" 
                    multiple="true" 
                    styleClass="searchField" >
    <p:ajax event="keypress" 
            actionListener="#{searchController.doSomething}" />
    </p:autoComplete>
```

This has no effects at all;
2)

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.searchField').find('input').keypress(
            function(ev){
                var keyCode = ev.keyCode;
                if (keyCode == 44) {
                    updateSearchField();
                }
                }
        );
    });
</script>
```

....

```
<p:autoComplete id="inputResID" 
                value="#{searchController.searchQuery}" 
                completeMethod="#{searchController.completeText}" 
                size="30" 
                maxResults="10" 
                multiple="true" 
                styleClass="searchField" >
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{searchController.handleSelect}" />
    <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" listener="#{searchController.handleUnselect}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

....

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateSearchField" update="inputResID" />
```

This will update the input field but it doesn't do the work defined in "#{searchController.completeText}".... So my question is, if it is possible at all to add a customized ajax event to work with the auto-completion component? If so what is the best way? Many thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Seems to me the problem is multiple="true". Is it a demand to have that?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the user could only select one of the options and then it is over.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**JS:**

```
function customFunction() {
    jQuery('input', '.searchField').keypress( function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 44) {
            updateSearchField();
        }
    });
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<p:ajax event="keypress" onstart="customFunction()" />
```

Hope this will help you. Good luck!